# Command pattern implementation

Tags: go, exception, solid-principles, command-pattern

I'm practicing with command pattern and faced a problem. If I get an exception after executing a command, I need to repeat it 2 times (by adding it to the command queue), and then write logs if it fails again. I can't think of how should I count it

The code:

```
cmd := queue.Take()
err := cmd.Execute()
if err != nil {
    // what i want to happen is the following
    if this cmd throws error 2 times, then {
        // Add the command to the command queue again
    } else if it threw error more than 2 times, then {
        // write logs
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to make it working this way. Also I'm trying to follow SOLID rules, no kludges. Please, share your thoughts, I will be glad to read them. Thanks in advance

Comment: Commands in queue can keep the number of retries, that way you know which command retried how many times.

Comment: To follow up on Burak's comment, use pointer to `type RetryCommand struct { retry int; cmd YourCommandType }` as the queue element.  Increment the `retry` field on error and retry as needed.